# How to test my Parse CouldCode Function?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I just started to work with `parse.com` `CloudCode`. I am really new to `Parse` development and I managed to deploy their code trough the command line tool.
there is a `main.js` file that contain this function:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("hello", function(request, response) {
    response.success("Hello world!");
});
```

now, I want to test and call this function, from the examples they told to run this function:

```
Parse.initialize('hQZZmu2UGiwr2QTHXrPSjG3ywAkFZccKQu12fD1S', 'IfaJZksyu21fKdITE0W8z9O2SWHpiLKlgUolfuRh');     
Parse.Cloud.run('hello', {}, {
success: function(result) {
    window.alert('success');
},
error: function(error) {
        window.alert('error');
    }
});
```

so, I am trying to call it from html file inside a

```
<script> //call to function here </script>
```

but nothing is happening.
I also try to add :

```
Parse.initialize('parse_id', 'js_key');
```

and still nothing.

can you please help?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming those are your correct application id and javascript parse keys. You can check these in your parse application's settings.

Make sure you are including parse.js before you call that script.

`<script src="//www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.4.2.min.js"></script>`

Finally you can check your parse application's logs in the dashboard to check if the function even got called on the backend.

Take a look at these links to help get started:
https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/web/existing

https://parse.com/docs/js/guide

Comment: i guess this is whats i am not doing. can you show me example of how to include this file?
of where he is located?

Comment: @orazran, I edited my answer showing you how to include the js file through the web. However, I am guessing you also downloaded a copy. If so, you can also include it with a relative file path like `<script src="js/parse-1.4.2.min.js"></script>` if it is in a folder called "js", and the "js" folder is in the same folder as your html file.